# 'Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to move a .csv file from VM to a Storage bucket. I've added the following code to my script

```
os.environ['xxx']=r"/home/xx/xxx.json"
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("bucket name")
data=bucket.blob("xxx.csv")
data.upload_from_filename(r"/home/xxx/xxxx/xxx.csv")
```

When I run the script from the SSH console it returns to me the following error

```
 raise exceptions.from_http_status(response.status_code, message, response=response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/sp500components/o
?uploadType=multipart: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Insufficient Permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Insufficient Permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}
: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

I've granted Storage admin privileges to my service account but the issue persists

**UPDATE:**

I've also found that there was a line which syntax was not correct. I missed the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']=r"xxxxx"
```

Comment: If you have added storage admin to your service account, you are not using that service account with your code. Your code is using ADC to located credentials. Add more details on your environment and how you have setup the service account for access by your program.

Answer (score 1):

You should add scopes to your VM so that it is allowed to communicate with the google cloud storage API. Documentation about setting instance scopes can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/set-scopes).

```
gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes example-instance  \
  --scopes=[SCOPES] \
  --zone=us-central1-b  \
  --service-account=example-account
```

The `scopes` flag contains at least one value or a comma-delimited string. In your case, it can be one of:

- cloud-platform
- storage-full
- storage-rw

Where the last one is preferred according to the principle of least privilege. You could also change this in the GCP console.

[image]